# How can i set retention period for state stores created by Kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I am using Streams DSL and doing stateful aggregation(Readin data from a topic, aggregating and writing data to another topic). How can i reduce the retention period of data that is written to the state store? Right now my infra team is saying that the data is retained for 5 years in the state store and i have to reduce that. Is there a specific configuration that i can set for how long the data should be retained?

```
    KTable<Windowed<String>, JSONObject> kTable = filteredKstream
            .groupBy((key, value) -> getNewKey(value),
                    Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), new JSONObjectSerde()))
            .windowedBy(windows).aggregate(() -> {
                SampleData sampleData = new SampleData();
                return new JSONObject(mapperUtils.writeValueAsString(sampleData, mapper));
            } , (key, value, aggregate) -> {
                return getAggregateValue(aggregate, value);
            } , Materialized
                    .<String, JSONObject, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>> as(
                            "sample-store")
                    .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                    .withValueSerde(jsonSerde));
```

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax i see that you have answered similar questions. so just wondering if you have any insights on this

Comment: Default retention time for stores is 1 day -- not sure why your team claims it's 5 years... Also, @michael-g-noll gave an answers. (Btw: tagging does not work this way -- I did not get a notification, but found the question just via browsing.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Materialized#withRetention()` to set the retention period of window and session stores.

https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Materialized.html#withRetention-java.time.Duration-